# SQL server login get unwanted high privileges on a db when created

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions, logins

We have a demand to create a new user with the ability to SELECT only 4 specific tables. In order to do that we create the login and map it to the requiered db :

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [pos] WITH PASSWORD=N'XXXX', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

USE [TARGETED_DB_NAME]
GO
CREATE USER [pos] FOR LOGIN [pos]
GO
```

After that, the user is able to do Any DML statement, whereas he has no privileges except the public role. We checked the public role permissions, server permissions etc but we don't find why the user can see all the tables of the database.

The problem is not present when we create the user on another database on the same instance.

Any idea why the login pos get such privileges ?

Comment: Does the public role have elevated permissions?

Comment: indeed the public role owns a schema called "SYSADM", and all the databases tables are prefixed by this schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following query would help to get insight of permissions that particular user got **Directly** or **Indirectly**, based on result you can analyse/identity what is the cause of problem.

```
USE [TARGETED_DB_NAME]
GO

Declare @UserName varchar (100) = 'username';

-- Permission applied to user (directly) -------------------------------------------------------------

select d.name, dp.* 
from sys.database_permissions as dp
        join sys.database_principals as d on dp.grantee_principal_id = d.principal_id
where d.name = (@UserName) --and dp.state = 'D'
order by d.principal_id

-- Permission applied to user (indirectly) -------------------------------------------------------------
select  dm.name as DB_UserName,
        sp.name as LoginName,
        dr.name as DB_RoleName,
        dp.[permission_name],
        dp.type,
        dp.state_desc
from sys.database_principals as dm  
        join sys.database_role_members as drm on dm.principal_id = drm.member_principal_id
        join sys.database_principals as dr on drm.role_principal_id = dr.principal_id
        left join sys.server_principals as sp on dm.sid = sp.sid
        left join sys.database_permissions as dp on dr.principal_id = dp.grantee_principal_id
Where (dm.name = @UserName or sp.name = @UserName) --and dr.name like 'db_deny%'
go
```

Comment: here the result, looks like the login have select permissions on two tables : name class class_desc major_id minor_id grantee_principal_id grantor_principal_id type permission_name state state_desc
pos 0 DATABASE 0 0 18 1 CO   CONNECT G GRANT
pos 1 OBJECT_OR_COLUMN 405576483 0 18 0 SL   SELECT G GRANT
pos 1 OBJECT_OR_COLUMN 421576540 0 18 0 SL   SELECT G GRANT

Comment: thanks. The login is not AD account but SQL login. nkdbajoe have provided a good clue above : he public role owns a schema called "SYSADM", and all the databases tables are prefixed by this schema. We are going to test it.

Comment: @Mickael, well, i thought, you are use with that _**We checked the public role permissions_** as you mentioned it in the question. However, in basic security point of view it's bad practice to grant additional permissions to `Public` role and `guest` users in SQL Server. I hope it's not production server.